# How to properly add DateTime to DotNet Core application?

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I use ubuntu:
I run: `$ dotnet run`
I get error:

`The type or namespace name 'DateTime' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

How can I add DateTime namespace in dotnet CORE app?

Comment: does `dotnet restore` show any errors? which version of the tooling (`dotnet --version`) are you using? can you share the .csproj file?